# Xamarin/Android - Location Listener Service call error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to create a wrapper for the location info such as longitude and altitude.  I create a class that extends from java.lang.object and implements ILocationListener.  I then created a `service` that creates an object of this class to get the latest longitude and latitude.  The code compiles without any errors.

Most of the code here are from the online sample. The problem is that I'm getting a runtime error saying `Can't create handler inside thread  that has not called Looper.prepare()`  Please note that there is no UI here.  I did try to pass the "this" as the context from the service but that didn't make any difference.

Anyone know why I'm getting the run time error about the Looper.prepare()?
Thanks in advance.

```
public  class GeoInfoService : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationListener
{
    public GeoInfo GeoInfoResult { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(30000)]
    public long MinimumTimeForUpdate { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(1)]
    public float MinimumDistanceForUpdate {get; set;}

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool isProviderEnabled { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
    public string Provider { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool hasError { get; set; }

    public System.Text.StringBuilder lastError { get; set; }

    LocationManager locMgr;
    string tag = "GeoInfoService";

    public GeoInfoService(Context context) 
    {
        lastError = new System.Text.StringBuilder ();
        MinimumTimeForUpdate = 2000;
        MinimumDistanceForUpdate = 1;

        locMgr =  context.GetSystemService (Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;

            var locationCriteria = new Criteria ();
            locationCriteria.Accuracy = Accuracy.NoRequirement;

            locationCriteria.PowerRequirement = Power.NoRequirement;// Power.Medium;
            string locationProvider = locMgr.GetBestProvider (locationCriteria, true);
            Log.Debug (tag, "Starting location updates with " + locationProvider.ToString ());


//THIS IS where we have the error java.lang.RuntimeException
//Can't create handler inside thread  that has not called Looper.prepare()
//  I also replaced "this" with context that was passed from the service

            locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates (locationProvider, MinimumTimeForUpdate, MinimumDistanceForUpdate, this);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got myself out of the `context` jungle.  My intention was that to create a class that I can new up on demand and get the `location` information.  But there are a couple of issues with that, the important one is that the `location` information is not cached and can only be obtained by `onLocationChange`.

So I just created a service and implemented ILocation interface and do all my logic in one place.